# Laplace's Equation Coordinate Change

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, coordinate-systems, chain-rule

I am reading Principles of Ideal-Fluid Aerodynamics by Karamcheti. In section 13.10 paged 400, he says:

> In cartesians we are to seek the solution of the equation
>
> $$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}=0\tag{13.20}\label{13.20}$$
>
> where $f(x,y)$ may be either the velocity potential or the stream
>   function. For the reasons outlined above, let us introduce a new set
>   of coordinates $q_1$ and $q_2$ such that
>
> $$
> \begin{array}{c}
> q_1=q_1(x,y) \\ 
> q_2=q_2(x,y) \\ 
> \end{array}\tag{13.21}\label{13.21}
> $$
>
> Let $g(q_1,q_2)$ correspond to $f(x,y)$. It may be verified that $\ref{13.20}$ then takes the form
>
> $$
> \begin{array}{c}
> \left[\left(\frac{\partial q_1}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial q_1}{\partial y}\right)^2\right]\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial q_1^2} +
> \left[\left(\frac{\partial q_2}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial q_2}{\partial y}\right)^2\right]\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial q_2^2}\\
> +\left(\frac{\partial^2q_1}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 q_1}{\partial y^2} \right)\frac{\partial g}{\partial q_1}
> +\left(\frac{\partial^2q_2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 q_2}{\partial y^2} \right)\frac{\partial g}{\partial q_2}\\
> +2\left(\frac{\partial q_1}{\partial x}\frac{\partial q_2}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial q_1}{\partial y}\frac{\partial q_2}{\partial y}\right)\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial q_1\partial q_2}=0
> \end{array}\tag{13.22}\label{13.22}
> $$

I am trying to verify equation $\ref{13.22}$. I believe when he says "let $g(q_1,q_2)$ correspond to $f(x,y)$" that it means the following:

$$ f(x,y) = f(x(q_1,q_2),y(q_1,q_2))=g(q_1,q_2)\tag{1}\label{1}$$

Then, from here I can substitute equation $\ref{1}$ into equation $\ref{13.20}$. I think my problem starts when I try to take $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ because the following seems wrong:

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial q_1}\frac{\partial q_1}{\partial x}\tag{2}\label{2}$$

I think I'm missing some form of the chain rule and believe $\ref{2}$ should really be something like

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial q_1}\frac{\partial q_1}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial g}{\partial q_2}\frac{\partial q_2}{\partial x}\tag{3}\label{3}$$

because if I make a small change in x, it may cause small changes in $q_1$ and $q_2$ as well. but I don't know how to prove this or if it is true.

Any help appreciated and thanks in advance!

Comment: You've noticed that $(1)$ 'seems wrong' because it is. When the author writes 'let $g(q_1,q_2)$ correspond to $f(x,y)$', they are really saying set $f(x,y) = g(q_1(x,y),q_2(x,y))$. Differentiating via the chain rule then gives you the result you found in $(3)$ which is _correct_, except for the middle term $\partial g/\partial x$ where you have used partial symbols. It should just be $\partial_{x} f = \partial_{q_{1}} g \cdot \partial_{x} q_{1} + \dots$.

Comment: Can you explain why $\ref{1}$ is incorrect? It seems to be the same thing you wrote except you showed how $q_1$ and $q_2$ are explicit functions of $x$ and $y$. Also, were you in agreement that $\ref{3}$ is in fact correct? -thanks!